# Rewriting a linear transformation as a finite product

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

My textbook (Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*) has the following proposition: every linear operator on $\mathbf{R}^k$ is a product of finitely many linear operators of the following three types:

1. those that permute basis elements;
2. those that scale a basis element and leave the other basis elements fixed;
3. those that add a basis element to another and leave the others fixed.

I'm not sure why this is true. I think it has to do with elementary matrices, and I can see why it would be true for invertible linear operators on $\mathbf{R^k}$, since invertible matrices are products of elementary matrices, but I don't see why it's true for every linear operator on $\mathbf{R}^k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user208658: If you are familiar with row reduction of matrices you know that a any matrix $A$, multiplied on the left by some invertible matrices of types $1$, $2$, or $3$, can brought to a row echelon form. This is from standard theory. Notice that if you deal with linear systems of equations, you are only making row transformations. Not take your new matrix in row echelon form that you obtained and do some column transformations to make $0$ the elements in the rows of the leadings ones, starting with the first row. In this way you get a matrix with some $1$'s in different rows and columns and the rest $0$. Do some permutations of the columns to bring all the $1$'s in the first $r$ columns ( $r$ is the rank of the matrix). To sum up

$U \cdot A \cdot V = A''$ where $U$, $V$ are invertible products of matrices of type $1$, $2$, $3$. Now $A''$ clearly is also a product of type $2$ ( some basic elements taken to $0$). You are almost done.

Comment: Just to clarify, does $U$ refer to the elementary matrices involved in row-reduction, and $V$ for column-reduction?

Is there a name in use to the process you describe w.r.t the column operations?

Comment: @user208658: Maybe column reduction. Or, row reductions of the transpose matrix, and then transpose again. About $U$, $V$, yes.

Comment: Oh, I see. The reason why you multiply on the right is because those matrices correspond to column operations.